# No property, bindable property, or event found for 'Loaded', or mismatching type between value and property

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am trying to get the app to execute a method on load. in my .xaml I have; `

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="LoginApp.Droid.Views.LocationPage"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"
             BackgroundColor="#E5FFC4"
             Loaded="LocationPage_Loaded">
```

While this is in my .xaml.cs file:

`public partial class LocationPage : ContentPage
{
    public LocationPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
    }`

```
private async void LocationPage_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
    locator.DesiredAccuracy = 50;

    var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3), includeHeading: true);

    Entry_Longitude.Text = position.Longitude.ToString();

    Entry_Latitude.Text = position.Latitude.ToString();

}
```

The error according to VS has to do with the line `Loaded="LocationPage_Loaded">` in the .xaml
Am I missing a xmlns namespace or something? How do I resolve the error?

Comment: Are you sure that you are pointing the correct class? x:Class="LoginApp.Droid.Views.LocationPage" the Droid part is suspicious.

Comment: I have just updated my Visual studio and when I reopened my solution squiggly lines now appear under the word 'Loaded' in the .xaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such `Event` called Loaded for `ContentPage`. However, in your case, you could override `OnAppearing()` in `LoactionPage.xaml.cs`

```
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
            locator.DesiredAccuracy = 50;

            var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3), includeHeading: true);

            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                Entry_Longitude.Text = position.Longitude.ToString();
                Entry_Latitude.Text = position.Latitude.ToString();
            });

        });

    }
```

this should achieve your goal.